# Is there a word for using multiple electronic devices at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests, technology

Right now i'm using my computer and iPad at the same time, basically just jumping between screens. Is there a word for this "screen-hopping"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft executive-turned-writer Linda Stone has worked mightily, I would say mostly unsuccessfully, to popularize the term ***[continuous partial attention](http://lindastone.net/qa/continuous-partial-attention/)*** (CPA), which [she carefully distinguishes](http://www.businessweek.com/business_at_work/time_management/archives/2008/07/continuous_part.html) from the more commonplace term ***multitasking***, for example in a 2008 *BusinessWeek* column:

> When we multi-task, we are motivated by a desire to be more productive and more efficient. Each activity has the same priority – we eat lunch AND file papers. We stir the soup AND talk on the phone. With multi-tasking, one or more activities is somewhat automatic, like eating lunch or stirring soup. …
>
> In the case of continuous partial attention, we’re motivated by a desire not to miss anything. There’s a kind of vigilance that is not characteristic of multi-tasking. With CPA, we feel most alive when we’re connected, plugged in and in the know. We constantly scan for opportunities – activities or people – in any given moment.

So if, for example, you are writing emails on the computer and have a movie playing in the background on the iPad, Stone would agree that you are multitasking; if you are switching constantly between the two, say writing email on one device and sending Tweets on the other, she would argue that you are in a state of CPA. But a web search on this term mostly turns up Stone's writings, or interviews with her, or articles [quoting her](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/07/05/opinion/05friedman.html?_r=0), and I do not think it has much currency.

---

The more generic term ***multitasking*** is older and more familiar; the Online Etymology Dictionary dates its origin to [1966](http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=multitasking) as a computing term. It sees a big surge in usage with the rise of microcomputing in the 1980s; I recall it being one of the little-understood buzzwords employed in the battle between Microsoft Windows and IBM OS/2 in the early 1990s (before *[multithreading](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/6424/en/)* became the rage).

[image: Google Ngram comparing multitasking and other terms]

Etymonline traces its use to describe human behavior to 1998, back when the future of human society was still doomed by media-obsessed "Gen-Xers" instead of by media-obsessed "Millenials."

Since then, this meaning has become prevalent, even [displacing the computing sense](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/multitask) in ODO and some other dictionaries. For the specific habit of consuming multiple media simultaneously— say, having a television show in in the background while reading a blog— the term ***[media multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_multitasking)*** stands out, but this sense appears to be pushing out other types of human multitasking, of the "[walking and chewing gum](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60299)" variety. It is the term writers use to [describe youth media consumption](http://kaiserfamilyfoundation.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/7592.pdf), warn and warn about [distracted pedestrians](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/03/25/business/25multi.html?_r=0), fret about the [future of the culture](http://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2007/11/the-autumn-of-the-multitaskers/306342/) and [our brain health](http://www.fastcompany.com/3036198/work-smart/people-who-jump-from-screen-to-screen-have-less-grey-matter-in-one-brain-region-s), and [mark our psychological limitations](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=95256794).

Comment: CPA is apparently poplar enough to be on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_partial_attention), and happens to be exactly what i'm looking for. Good point about the popularity of multitasking as well.

Answer (score 2):

*Multitasking* is the ability to do more than one thing at a time. I cannot think of something which applies specifically to technology.

Comment: Multitasking is good, but is there something specifically about technology?

Comment: *Multiteching? Multi-e-tasking?*

Answer (score 2):

You can consider ***multi-device usage*** or ***multi-device switching*** also.

I have found  articles/studies about this topic with a quick search on Google. Below is a citation from one of the articles:

> This comes from a new multi-device study, conducted by Facebook in collaboration with GfK, revealing people’s behaviour when it comes to moving across devices (smartphone, tablet and desktop) on a day-to-day basis.
>
> It’s becoming increasingly common practice to switch to a different device, even though we may have started a task on a different one all together.
>
> https://econsultancy.com/blog/64464-more-than-40-of-online-adults-are-multi-device-users-stats#i.pdznn69qnfres2

The article also mentions the stats from the study under multi-device switching title:

> In the UK, more than 60% of online adults use at least two devices every day and nearly 25% use three devices.
>
> - 40% of all online adults start an activity on one device and finish it on another.
> - This number increases with the amount of devices owned: 54% of people who own two devices switch between them to complete tasks or activities and 73% of people who have three devices do the same.
> - Among those who switched devices in the study, 25% switched to a tablet and 60% switched to a laptop.

---

Answer (score 2):

You have some good answers, but there is another term for the specific practice of simultaneously using multiple devices:

> dual-screening

Most commonly used to describe tweeters watching TV and tweeting about it, though also applicable to other uses of multiple screens: using a smartphone while gaming, or watching Netflix on a tablet while doing work on a desktop, etc. It's a very popular term with marketing people, who see it as the next big thing.

http://www.marketingweek.co.uk/disciplines/market-research/dual-screening-tweeters-provide-opportunities-for-brands/4005531.article

http://www.mycustomer.com/topic/marketing/brands-capitalising-dual-screening-increase-twitter-presence/161796

http://www.thedrum.com/knowledge-bank/2014/01/23/don-t-assume-mobile-usage-means-business-people-are-move

Comment: That's a good option too.